# Is there a way to access data from other groups when summarising data in R without using a loop?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, purrr

I'm just starting to use data.table to analyse some high dimensional data, where I have several clusters and several markers.  I'd like to be able to use the 'by' function but to be able to access the data outside of the group, i.e. by = !group.  I'm trying to compare statistics of the group to non-group.

I've had a look through the documentation, and the .SD looks intriguing, but doesn't seem to quite hold the answer to me as it only allows access to the grouped data.table.  I'm sure I can do this using either a loop or apply, but I don't think this will be nearly as fast as if it were possible with data.table.

```r
library(data.table)
library(purrr)

data.table(iris) %>%
    melt %>%
    .[, .(mean = mean(value)), by = .(Species, variable)] %>%
    dcast(Species ~ variable)
```

This allows me to get summary statistics for the group:

```
#       Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1:     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
# 2: versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
# 3:  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026
```

But say I wanted to find the mean(value) by group - mean(value) by !group

```
data.table(iris) %>%
    melt %>%
    .[variable == "Petal.Length"] %>%
    .[, group := Species == "setosa"] %>%
    .[, .(means = mean(value)), by = group] 

#    group means
# 1:  TRUE 1.462
# 2: FALSE 4.906
```

This would be a way to find it for one cluster(setosa) and one marker(Petal.Length), but I can't see how to scale this up.

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: I think Cole has provided the output in the most useful way.  For my example I was planning on returning a table similar to the table of means in the second code section, but with mean(values)(for group) - mean(values)(for !group).  If that makes sense.  But I agree with Cole that leaving the data.table in the long format is helpful for calculating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(iris)
molten_dt <- melt(dt)

molten_dt[, .(means = mean(value),
              other_means = mean(molten_dt[Species != .BY[[1]] & variable == .BY[[2]], value])
            ),
          by = .(Species, variable)]

       Species     variable means other_means
 1:     setosa Sepal.Length 5.006       6.262
 2: versicolor Sepal.Length 5.936       5.797
 3:  virginica Sepal.Length 6.588       5.471
 4:     setosa  Sepal.Width 3.428       2.872
 5: versicolor  Sepal.Width 2.770       3.201
 6:  virginica  Sepal.Width 2.974       3.099
 7:     setosa Petal.Length 1.462       4.906
 8: versicolor Petal.Length 4.260       3.507
 9:  virginica Petal.Length 5.552       2.861
10:     setosa  Petal.Width 0.246       1.676
11: versicolor  Petal.Width 1.326       1.136
12:  virginica  Petal.Width 2.026       0.786
```

To understand what's happening, this code is helpful to run:

```
molten_dt[, print(.BY), by = .(Species, variable)]
```

Comment: That's genius, I wasn't aware of the .BY feature.  This also returns a data.table that I can use to calculate the values I am looking for.  Thank you.